# Riemann-like sum for infinite integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

Under what conditions does $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f \left(\frac{k}{n} \right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx ? $

I think I read somewhere that it's only true for monotonic functions (assuming that the integral converges, of course). But it seems to be true for other functions as well. And do we refer to this as a Riemann sum?

Comment: For any fixed n this is indeed the Riemann sum with the partition $\{[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}] \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. It's true for all continuous functions if you replace $\infty$ with any nonnegative real number.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} f \left(\frac{k}{n} \right) =\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \ dx $

Comment: If you remove the middle equality, that's true for all continuous functions.

Comment: I thought a Riemann sum is only defined for a bounded function on a closed interval.  So what I'm asking about is not exactly a Riemann sum.  And I was trying to show (in response to someone who deleted his comment) why I wasn't summing from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, technically Riemann sums are defined for continuous functions on closed intervals (which makes them automatically bounded). So in your case it's really a limit of Riemann sums.

Comment: But isn't $\displaystyle \lim_{n,b \to \infty} \frac{b}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} f \left(\frac{kb}{n} \right)$ something fundamentally different than what I have written above?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8047/discussion-between-julien-clancy-and-random-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be too useful but it is something. Assume that $f$ is continuous. Define $g_n(m) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n} + m)$. We have the following equalities:

$
\int_0^\infty f = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \int_m^{m+1}f = \sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n} + m)\right) = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(m)
$

If we could exchange the limit and sum we would have

$
\int_0^\infty f = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(m) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m = 0}^\infty g_n(m) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n} + m) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(\frac{k}{n})
$

We wish to know under what circumstances we can exchange the limit and the sum. By Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem this is possible when $|g_n| \leq h$ for all $n$ for some integrable function $h$, i.e. when we can find $h(m)$ with $\int_0^\infty |h| < \infty$ and $h (m) \geq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n} + m)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Can we extrapolate for what sorts of functions $f$ that would be true?

Comment: Ones that go to zero "fast enough". It includes, for instance, the $f(x) = 0$ if $x < 1$ and $f(x) = \sin x / x^2$ if $x \geq 1$ (this is dominated by $h(x) = 0$ if $x < 1$ and $f(x) = 1 / x^2$ if $x \geq 1$, for instance). This class certainly includes functions that are not in the class you mentioned above (monotonic functions). Intuitively you should be able to derive that theorem from this one; as a sketch if a function goes to zero quickly enough it is dominated, and if not both sides are infinite.

Comment: P.S. "Fast enough" means asymptotically any faster than $1/x$.